# Antivirus for Linux machines

Tags: gratis, linux, antivirus

Is there a free antivirus for Linux (I am using Ubuntu) that contains a sandbox and is tested to be effective?

I especially need a sandbox because sometimes when an unknown file is downloaded, I can test if it is safe before I actually open it.

Comment: this are rather 2 questions: concerning antivirus for linux, your question is a duplicate of this: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/38531/9157 - and thinking about security & sandboxes [Qubes OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubes_OS) comes in my mind...

Comment: ...but for sure, using a virtual machine (or even better a live-system) would be the best solution, if you are working with suspicious files/software.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just try the software out on a live bootable USB (and/or VirtualBox or another virtual machine; I'd rather use the live USB, personally, for performance; you can install a lot of stuff on those, which will disappear when you shut down). Or, if it doesn't require sudo or root, just log into a guest session (everything you do in that home directory will be reset after you log out, if you have it set up).

I've never heard of an antivirus that contains a sandbox, although I haven’t used anti-virus software much since 2007 or so, when I switched to Linux from Windows. I wonder if you’ve seen this feature on an antivirus for another OS.

Linux isn’t really known for viruses, but if there’s antivirus software (and there is), there must be some viruses out there somewhere. Clamwin is the popular free antivirus for Linux. I can’t vouch for its efficacy, as I’ve never found a virus with it (LOL), but it’s free and people seem to like it.

Anyway, you’re probably more likely to install other forms of malware than viruses (e.g. bloatware, spyware, software that accidentally messes up your computer, etc.), although you’re probably safer sticking to the regular software channels if you want more tried and true stuff.